# Relationship between Hardy-Orlicz space and the corresponding Orlicz space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, function-spaces, orlicz-spaces

For $p \in [1, \infty]$ the Hardy space $H_p$ is defined as the space of all analytic functions $f$ on the open disk satisfying
$$\|f\|_{H_p} = \sup_{0 < r < 1} \|f(r\cdot)\|_{L_p(\mathbb{T})} < \infty$$

If $\varphi$ is an Orlicz function, we could define a Hardy-Orlicz space $H_{\varphi}$ by the condition:
$$\|f\|_{H_\varphi} = \sup_{0 < r < 1} \|f(r\cdot)\|_{L_\varphi(\mathbb{T})} < \infty$$

It is known that we can identify $H_p$ with the subspace of $L_p(\mathbb{T})$ of functions which Fourier series have nonzero coefficients only for the nonnegative part of the series. I mean that $f \sim \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n e^{inx}$. Also, if $1 < p < \infty$ then $H_p$ is complemented in $L_p(\mathbb{T})$.

Are there corresponding results for Hardy-Orlicz spaces?